# how to implement dialogfragment in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialogfragment

I have a question about dialogfragment - I created a class with dialogfragment by tutorial, but in the tutorial, the dialogfragment was shown by button click - I want to show dialogfragment by clicking on fragment tab in my MainActivity - I can't figure out how.. I have Fragment GetItem method, where i have empty case 4 in my code - It's the fragment, where I want to open dialogfragment by clicking on it. there are my codes. Thanks for all help and answers! Sorry if something isn't clear..

-Problem is fixed (viz comments) - I created new DialogFragment - xml file and java class - codes from  guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment#build-dialo‌​g and then I added this codes to MainActivity

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                if (position == 4) {
                    showAlertDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void showAlertDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        EditNameDialogFragment alertDialog = EditNameDialogFragment.newInstance("Some title");
        alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you you return a new MediaFragment?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to detect which tab is clicked and show the dialog like any other

You need to add a TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener

Set that up

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      super.onTabSelected(tab);
      int position = tab.getPosition();
      if (position == 4) {
          // Create MediaFragment here
      } 
   }
});
```

Comment: Isn't the ontabselected method Fragment getItem (int position)? And I want to call the action in case 4. But i tried your code and I don't know where am i Supposed to add MediaFragment and the OnTabSelectedListener is strikedthrough.. Also position is red highlighted and i changed numTab into display_num and it was fine. I think you know the way, please see my codes above, maybe It should help! Thanks a lot for the helping and the answers!

Comment: `getItem (int position)` is for the ViewPager adapter, your question asked about selecting only a tab of TabLayout.  Case 4 is handled by `position == 4`. You add the Fragment within the if statement. You can search elsewhere how to actually display a DialogFragment. I have fixed the variable names

Comment: I am sorry about my english and Java knowledge and I appreciate your patience with me and helping. Well, your new code fixed well.. I am not sure I asked my question right, I am trying to open DialogFragment (edited in MediaFragment) by clicking the tab item, or I don¨t know how its called.. just the window on the up toolbar (just in case my description wasn't good). So i added your code into onCreate method and I added Intent intentMF = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MediaFragment.class);
startActivity(intentMF); and I let the case 4 empty and it isn't working (I know its my bad) thx for help

Comment: `MediaFragment.class` is a **Fragment** class. You cannot call `startActivity` on it since it is not an Activity. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment#build-dialog

Comment: Well, I added some codes above, I think It should look something like that, but in my MediaFragment I have different kind of code, so I have no newInstance method, so I don't know what to do now, also my (fm, "fragmen_alert") is red underlined. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You don't need newInstance, but you're welcome to define it. I suggest you read that whole page rather than only copy one section of it

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I read this article, but the DialogFragment is completely different from mine (codes above) and I don't really know how to use that clicklisener on tab fragmen in my app.. Anyway thanks for good learning stuff, but when I always tried to use those methods and codes in my app, nothing did work. Thanks for answers and helping!

Comment: If you read that site carefully, it shows you how to define `newInstance` method. Or you only need `new MediaFragment()` also, you must use the Support V4 import to the DialogFragment class. So delete this line `import android.app.DialogFragment`, and try to import that again

Comment: I finally fixed my problem - I completely overrided whole dialogfragment and method in MainActivity - Ill add my codes above if someone will have same issues. Thanks a lot man for everything!

Answer (score 0):

see the android [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) :

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
    MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}
```

}